# Find and replace strings in raw ASN.1 encoded data

Tags: python, asn.1

I have some ASN.1 BER encoded raw data which looks like this when opened in notepad++:
[Sample ASN1 encoded data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJYNP.png)

I believe it's in binary octect format so only the "IA5string" data types are readable/meaningful.

I'm wanting to do a find and replace on certain string data that contains sensitive information (phone numbers, IP address, etc), in order to scramble and anonymise it, while leaving the rest of the encoded data intact.

I've made a python script to do it and it will work fine on plain text data, but having encoding/decoding issues when trying to read/write files in this encoded format, I guess since it contains octect values outside the ASCII range.

What method would I need to use to import this data, do find & replace on the strings to create a modified file that leaves everything else intact? i think it should be possible without completely decoding the raw ASN.1 data with a schema, since I only need to work on the IA5String data types

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it will be that simple. You want to replace some content in ASN.1 (TLV). That means you will change the lenth of ASN.1 node and this will impact length of parent node etc. You only (safe) way is to decode ASN.1 object, replace sensitive values and encode it back.

Comment: Hmm, there would be a way to do this only if you do not change the length of each sensitive data meaning you will replace each character with i.e. zero. But I am not sure if it will be secure. Maybe there will be a way to deduce some information from it (like if it is a mobile number) based on the length of the value.

Comment: Yeah I won't be changing length of anything, just replacing characers with others. I have regex to detect sensitive data types. The only problem is the data encoding/decoding in python

Comment: Most reliable way would be to decode octets stream into ASN.1 data structures, then wipe out sensitive parts and encode the data structures back into octets stream. That might be possible to do in Python (with pyasn1 or other tools), but you need to know the grammar used to encode your data.